# Linear and Logarithmic Constraint in Semidefinite Programming

Tags: entropy, semidefinite-programming, cvx

I am trying to minimize the largest component of a vector $x = [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$, where $x_1 \ge x_2 ... \ge x_4$, such that it satisfies a set of linear inequalities $A, b$ in the following way:

$$
Ax \le b.
$$

Furthermore, I want that, the Shannon entropy of the vector $x$ satisfies the following:

$$
-\sum_i x_i \log_2(x_i) = q,
$$
for some constant $q$.

I can write the following for the first constraint:

```
cvx_begin sdp

variable x(4, 1) 

minimize x(1)
subject to 
    A * x <= b

cvx_end
```

However, when I try to include the second constraint, like:
`quantum_entr(diag(x)) == q.`

I get the following error:

```
Invalid constraint: {concave} == {real constant}
```

Is there a way to mix these two types of constraints in a semi-definite program? Thanks!

Comment: Semidefinite programs have only linear and semidefinite constraints. I don't see any semidefinite constraints so I'm not quite sure why this is tagged as an SDP. Also cvx has a function for the shannon entropy `entr()`.

Comment: I see, thanks Rammus. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Secondly the error you are getting from CVX is telling you that a constraint $f(x) = c$ where $f$ is a concave function is not a valid constraint. It violates the [DCP ruleset](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html). Basically your problem is not guaranteed to be a convex optimization problem (and it probably isn't), so cvx can't help you. You can't have in general a convex/concave function equality constraint. For example, consider a constraint $x^2 = 1$, then the feasible set is $x = \{-1, +1\}$ which is not a convex set. Note however that $x^2 \leq 1$ does lead a convex set.

Comment: You can relax your problem to $- \sum_i x_i \log x_i \geq q$ if you want to make it convex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rammus. Let me try this.